# jQuery table row animate doesn't override the class styles

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fade the background of a row in/out when it gets edited.  Here is the code I have once the ajax post is complete:

```
.done(function (data) {
    //animate row background colour
    var row = $('#tblTasks_' + data.JobId + ' tbody tr[data-id="' + data.TaskId + '"]');
    var bgcolour = $(row).css('backgroundColor');
    $(row).animate({
        "background-color": "#d9534f"
    }, 1500).delay(1000).animate({
        "background-color": bgcolour
    }, 1500);
```

This works fine for rows that have no classes, however some of the rows in the table can be marked as "completed", in which case I add the class 'success', and bootstrap styles it green for me, so the user knows the item in that row is marked as completed.  For whatever reason, this background animation doesn't work for those rows.

I can somewhat achieve what I want done this way:

```
.done(function (data) {
    //animate row background colour
    var row = $('#tblTasks_' + data.JobId + ' tbody tr[data-id="' + data.TaskId + '"]');
    var hasClass = $(row).hasClass('success');
    $(row).removeClass('success');
    var bgcolour = $(row).css('backgroundColor');
    $(row).animate({
        "background-color": "#d9534f"
    }, 1500).delay(1000).animate({
        "background-color": bgcolour
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function () {
            if (hasClass) $(row).addClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

However, it's not ideal, because it looks a little choppy as it removes the class and adds it back in.

Why doesn't the animate function work on rows that have classes?  I was under the impression that inline styles should override classes?  Does anyone have a better suggestions on how to handle this?

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because, when you apply bootstrap 'success' class to a row in a table, background property is actually applied to its children (td and th) and not on the actual 'tr'. If you inspect it in chrome, it should be obvious. All you have to do to fix this is add '.children()' to your jquery target.

In your first block code doing this:

```
$(row).children().animate....
```

will fix it. I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrshaLgy/3/) to demo this.

Do remember, that after your animation is finished, your code leaves it at, 'bgcolor', so you will have to change the `bgcolor` to detect the `td` color as I have shown in the jsfiddle.